# VLC shows green screen on playing MKV

Tags: drivers, video, vlc

I am trying to play a MKV video in VLC.

Instead of the video, I see just green screen and only sound.

The random fixes I found on the internet didn't help.

- Turning off the "accelerated output" didn't help
- Installing 01.org / intel.com drivers for 15.10 didn't help

I will write whatever output is needed here.

This is the output VLC itself gives

```
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1-0-ga425c42)
[0000000001da6088] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00007f8028d384a8] dts decoder: DTS channels:6 samplerate:48000 bitrate:1536000
libva info: VA-API version 0.38.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_38
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[00007f8028c0c5a8] avcodec decoder: Using OpenGL/VAAPI/libswscale backend for VDPAU for hardware decoding.
WARNING: Unsupported the FMO/ASO constraints!!!
[00007f7ff0001268] vdpau_display vout display error: video mixer surface width capabilities query failure: VDP_STATUS_NO_IMPLEMENTATION
Stream with high frequencies VQ coding
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

`lspci | grep VGA` returns `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)`

I will install whatever is needed

Answer (score 1):

My own non-solution:

- install kaffeine instead of VLC through apt-get
- open `~/.kde/share/apps/kaffeine/xine-config`
- find the commented `#video.driver:auto` line
- replace it with `video.driver:vdpau`, remove the comment
- grind teeth at the terrible kaffeine interface, but still use it instead of VLC